# Creating menu of sqlite content

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to create a menu of the content in my SQLite. I want the links to open each article. I want the links to open underneath the menu, but at the moment I can´t get them to open at all.  I'm very much a beginner at this so I imagine I'm far off what it´s supposed to be coded. Because, now, every time I click a link the page just reloads. It´d be much appreciated if someone could help me or point me in the right direction!

This is the code:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:$dbPath");

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Article;');
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 


?>
  <?php foreach($res as $article): ?>
  <ul class="aside">
     <li class="aside"><a href="menu.php?=<?php echo $article['id']; ?>"><?php echo $article['id']; ?></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the code snippet you provide is in menu.php

First, your url parameter in menu link should be in the form : key=value

```
<a href="menu.php?article_id=<?php echo $article['id']; ?>">
```

Then you have to process that information (the presence of the article_id in the url) in order to present the content of that article.

You access the url parameter with the superglobals variable (provided by PHP) $_GET.

You may test if an article_id was provided in the url (meaning the user clicked on a link), get the article information with an sql request and display these informations.

```
if (!empty($_GET['article_id'])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Article WHERE id = :articleId');
    $stmt->execute(array(':articleId' => $_GET['article_id']));
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $article = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // your display code here :)
        print_r($article);
    }
}
```

Anyway, having a code displaying an article in a file named "menu.php" is weird ;) You should separate menu.php and article.php for example, including menu.php from article.php. That will be easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! I'm not going to put the article in menu.php, it was just an example to show what I needed help with :)